# mysql regex() alternation match order?

Tags: mysql, preg-match

With the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name REGEXP(bob|robert)
```

Am I right in assuming that mysql will scan each row in a fairly random order looking for either 'bob' or 'robert' (rather than bob first, then another scan for robert)?

If so, is there any way to get mysql to attempt to match the entire table against 'bob' first and then 'robert' without performing two seperate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name REGEXP(bob|robert) order by name desc
```

It is only one query, and do the job.

SGBD can scan the data as they are please to do, it is not specify in SQL, and it is not random.

*Unspecified can be random but isn't random.*

Comment: `ORDER BY name` is going to order it alphabetically though isn't it?

Comment: yes, I have miss read the question at first, and already commit an update with the 'desc' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

There is no logical way to match the entire table against `bob` first (why would you want to?)

You can order the results, though, but it can be slow if the table has high cardinality and/or `name` is not a key.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = 'bob' OR name = 'robert'
ORDER BY name = 'bob' DESC
```

Comment: Could that also be used for a REGEX() or LIKE match? The reason I was using regex is because I am matching an unknown number of items and REGEX seemed easier than a loop in PHP to build the query.

Comment: @JamesNapier yes you can; you could use `REGEXP`/`LIKE` in `ORDER BY` as well